# How to enforce implementing the constructor of a specific data type on a derived class?

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class

Given an abstract class A and a data type T, is there a way to enforce implementing a constructor of T on a derived class of A? i.e.

```
class A {
public:
   virtual ~A() {}
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class B : public A {
public:
   B(T t) { ... } // this constructor must be implemented otherwise compilation will error out
};
```

Comment: From which point, and to which end?

Comment: Why does it matter to `A` how derived classes are created?

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible** with a private token based design. This idea looks something like the following:

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

class A{
private:
  struct create_token 
  { 
    create_token(const create_token &) = delete; 
    create_token& operator=(const create_token &) = delete; 
    create_token(create_token &&) = default; 
    create_token& operator=(create_token &&) = default; 
    friend class A;
      private:
    create_token(){};
  };
  inline static auto token = create_token{};
protected:
  A(create_token) {}
public:
  template<class T, typename... ARGUMENTS>
  static std::unique_ptr<T> create(ARGUMENTS&&... arguments)
  {
    // Whatever creation mechanism here
    return std::make_unique<T>(create_token{}, std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...);
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  template <typename Token> // Can't name A::create_token, it is private
  B(Token tok) : A(std::move(tok)) {}
  B(){} // Will always lack a `create_token`
};
```

The example needs a bit of modification for your case (mainly to restrict the constructor) - but the point is that construction can only go through the factory `create` function.

Comment: There is a way to "pick" this lock: https://godbolt.org/z/S1zjzh
However, that is easy enough to thwart by giving `create_token` some behavior that is actually hideable in `A` (e.g. requiring some state, not just any instance of `create_token`. That could then be hidden away in some library, unlike the templated `create`).

Comment: More generally, it would be possible to create some helper code to obtain a valid token from `A` for a dummy `A`-derived class class and then use those tokens to write arbitrarily-parametrized constructors in other `A`-derived classes. I don't expect that to be relevant in most cases (such an attacker might as well go to reverse engineering/code injection) but it's a C++-conforming way to break out of this interface.

Comment: @MaxLanghof indeed -  it's easy enough to thwart as it is - like you have demonstrated. My point is that it is possible **by design** at the language level - I don't have time atm. to polish off the answer, maybe later.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have updated the example - now using friend + private constructor - that should stop the immediate Stealing, wouldn't you say ?

Answer (score 0):

If `A` will have it's own constructor which takes parameter and no default constructor

```
class A {
public:
   A(T t) {};
   virtual ~A() {}
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Then all derived classes have to initialize that in their constructor, which means *at least one* constructor will be needed.

See below examples:

```
class B : public A {
public:
   B(T t):A(t) { ... } // pass parameter to A constructor
};

class C : public A {
public:
   C(): A(T{}) { ... } // initialize A with a default T
};

class D : public A {
public:
   using A::A; // inherit A's constructors
};

class E : public A {
public:
    //error - doesn't work without any constructor!
};
```

You shouldn't try to force any constructor syntax in derived classes - they may know things which you don't know and they may or may not need T. I'm not sure if forcing constructor signature is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

My best shot would be using CRTP, so that you can check the properties of the derived class within the base class:

```
template <class Derived>
class A_CRTP //: public A_Base
{
protected:
  A() {
    static_assert(sizeof(Derived{T}) > 0, "Constructor from T not present");
  }
};

class B : public A_CRTP<B> {
public:
  B();
  B(T); // removing this is a compile-time error.
};
```

However, this is trivially bypassed:

```
class C : public B
{
  C();
  // No C(T) needed, B has that and A doesn't know about C.
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qzd_LJ

That makes this whole exercise somewhat pointless, as it just forces users to take extra steps before they can write the set of constructors *they* want (see answer of @Yksisarvinen).

Comment: You can move the `static_assert` into e.g. a constructor of `A_CRTP`, so that `B` is complete by the time it is instantiated.

Comment: @MaxLanghof another point is that you aren't required to pass the derived type, eg. `class B : public A_CRTP<C> {` could work - so it is relying on benign use